# DropDownListFor not changing selected value when I select a new value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am wondering if anyone knows why my dropdownlistfor is not changing and posting back the new value to the controller when I change the option in the select list. The select list is within a forloop which shows multiple items with multiple select lists so the user can change the item they have selected to a new one.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.PoItemsList.Count; i++)
{
    net += Convert.ToDecimal(Model.PoItemsList[i].Net);
    vat += Convert.ToDecimal(Model.PoItemsList[i].Vat);
    gross += Convert.ToDecimal(Model.PoItemsList[i].Gross);
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PoItemsList[i].Id)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PoItemsList[i].NCodeId)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PoItemsList[i].ItemRef, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PoItemsList[i].Description, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width: 200px;" })
        </td>
        <td>
            @*@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PoItemsList[i].NCodeId, Model.NominalCodeList, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ncode" })*@
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PoItemsList[i].NCodeId, new SelectList(Model.NominalCodeList, "Value", "Text", Model.PoItemsList[i].NCodeId), new { @class = "form-control"})
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PoItemsList[i].CostPerItem, new { @class = "form-control", @Value = Convert.ToDecimal(Model.PoItemsList[i].CostPerItem) })
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PoItemsList[i].Quantity, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width: 50px;" })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PoItemsList[i].Net, new { @class = "form-control cpd-align-right", @Value = Convert.ToDecimal(Model.PoItemsList[i].Net) })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PoItemsList[i].Vat, new { @class = "form-control cpd-align-right", @Value = Convert.ToDecimal(Model.PoItemsList[i].Vat) })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PoItemsList[i].Gross, new { @class = "form-control cpd-align-right", @Value = Convert.ToDecimal(Model.PoItemsList[i].Gross) })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ManualEntry, new {@class = "form-control"})
        </td>                          
        <td>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger centre" value="X" onclick="DeleteItemAndSave(@Model.PoItemsList[i].Id)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Are other properties in the PoItemsList being populated appropriately when the you do a post back?

Comment: Yes if i change anything else in the poitemlist eg.description the changes are posted back to the controller fine.

Comment: Follow @Ade Stringer answer and see what happens

Comment: All working now thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PoItemsList[i].NCodeId)` and a drop down list bound to the same item; remove the hidden input and your code should work fine.

Comment: You sir are a life saver!